# Read issue from JSON

Tags: r, rvest, jsonlite

I have xml file stored here. It contains json. I am unable to read and convert it to dataframe

**Cleaning code**

```
htext <- html_nodes(content, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'home_js_model')]") %>% html_text()
htext <- gsub("<script type=\"text/javascript\">", "", htext, fixed=TRUE)
htext <- gsub("var home_js_model = {", "", htext, fixed=TRUE)
htext <- gsub("</script>", "", htext, fixed=TRUE)
htext <- gsub("stock\":", "", htext, fixed=TRUE)
```

**Read from JSON**

```
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(htext)
```

I tried this as well but didn't get success.

```
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", htext)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't get success"? Are you getting any errors? Is `json` empty or `NULL`? What is the value of `htext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to trim off the `var home_js_model =`  from the start and and the semicolon from the end to parse the json. However, the result is a very long, very complicated nested listed, so your parsing woes may just be starting...

```r
jsonlite::fromJSON(substr(htext, 21, 5615711))
#> $stock
#> $stock$period_title
#> [1] "1T2018"
#>
#> $stock$total
#> [1] 4162848
#>
#> $stock$total_sale
#> [1] 3426559
#>
#> $stock$total_rental
#> [1] 736289
#>
#> $stock$total_es
#> [1] 2196851
#>
#> ... (very very long list)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we convert it into dataframe?

Comment: Can you please include the code you used for text cleaning?

Comment: @john I didn't use any text cleaning. I downloaded the link that you posted in your question. The object `htext` appeared in my global workspace, and the above code allowed the list to be created.

Comment: @john the list is a collection of different types of data of different lengths. It doesn't make sense to convert it into a data frame, and wouldn't really be possible. You could probably coerce it into several different data frames. At least two of the objects in the list are already data frames :. If you do `my_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(substr(htext, 21, 5615711))` then `my_json$ranking$sales` and `my_json$ranking$rental` are both data frames

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. To make it dynamic I am trimming off (as suggested) str_trim(htext). How can i trim off semi column from the end dynamically?

Comment: @john you could try `gsub(";\\W*$", "", htext)`

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this but it returns lexicon error htext <- str_trim(htext)
htext <- gsub(";\\W*$", "", htext)
jstext <- jsonlite::fromJSON(htext)[1]

Comment: @john is this using the exact text that you posted in your question? You need to remove the `var variable = ` part from the start of the text. `str_trim` only removes whitespace.